# How to exequte mssql query with function?

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine

I want to run a mssql query that has a part of the user defined function.
This is my code:

```
$connection = $this->em->getConnection();

$sql = 'select * from ssm.table where ip = dbo.fn_ConvertIpAddressToBinary(\'192.168.0.1\')';

$result = $connection->executeQuery($sql);
$results = $result->fetchAll();

var_dump($results);
```

However, I get a blank response. If you set the request without function, everything works fine. This query works fine in sql query analyzer.

What can I do wrong?

Comment: Does the query return rows in SQL-Server Managment-Studio? I mean not Query Analyzer

Comment: In Sql Server Managment Studio this query works fine.

Comment: please state the user that you impersonate in PHP to run the query and also the one that you use to login in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

try rewrite as:
$sql = "select * from ssm.table where ip = dbo.fn_ConvertIpAddressToBinary('192.168.0.1')";